# How to run housekeeping tasks before processing hosts in inventory file?

Tags: ansible

First two tasks in my playbook are ran on `localhost` and are configured with `run_once: yes`. However, they are still executed against first entry in my inventory file:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts add_user.yaml
ticket number: 678
Junos commit comment: test change
Junos configuration file: users.conf

PLAY [Apply configuration-template to Juniper devices.] ************************

TASK [Update CVS] **************************************************************
changed: [10.10.10.111 -> localhost]

TASK [Create directory /home/users/ansible/678 for conf diffs and debugging logs] ***
changed: [10.10.10.111 -> localhost]

TASK [Change Junipers configuration] *******************************************
changed: [10.10.10.112] => (item=/home/user/playbooks/users.conf)
changed: [10.10.10.111] => (item=/home/user/playbooks/10.10.10.111/users.conf)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.10.10.111              : ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
10.10.10.112              : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

$
```

As seen in `PLAY RECAP`, for `10.10.10.111` there were three tasks executed. Is there a more graceful way to do this? I guess one option is to add `localhost` to inventory file and run first two tasks with condition similar to `when: inventory_hostname == "localhost"` and third task with `when: inventory_hostname =! "localhost"`? However, maybe it is possible to run such housekeeping tasks before running tasks against entries in inventory file?

Comment: So what is the problem? You don't like the way Ansible displays the log? Then why is it titled "*How to run housekeeping tasks before processing hosts in inventory file?*" -- do the tasks run incorrectly? And why don't you simply create another play?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer if Ansible displays the log in `PLAY RECAP` in a way that two tasks were executed for `localhost`, one task for `10.10.10.111` and one task for `10.10.10.112`. If I create another play, then there seems to be no way to export variables(facts) from first play do another. Sorry that I did not mention this in my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your playbook in 2 plays, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "ticket_number"
      prompt: "ticket number"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ticket_number: "{{ ticket_number }}"
    # housekeeping tasks

- hosts: servers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost.ticket_number
    # servers config tasks
```

**EDIT:** I added a `vars_prompt` combined with a `set_fact` to show how vars can be accessed from one play to another with `hostvars`.

Comment: This would work fine, but `housekeeping tasks` and `servers config tasks` share some variables. In other words I need to prompt(`vars_prompt:`) the user to enter some variables in first play and I need to use those same variables in second play. I tried to accomplish this with `set_fact:`, but even this does not seem to allow export variables between the plays.

Comment: `vars_prompt` are local to the play, so you can't access it from the second play. But facts are global and can be accessed with `hostvars`. See my edit for the details.